# thunderbird sends pdf as plain/text

Tags: thunderbird

I am under Lubuntu 12.10 with thunderbird 16.0.2

When I send a pdf file, people who receive it cannot open this pdf with acrobat or evince. It appears that in the source of the mail, thunderbird said that my pdf file is a plain/text file instead of a binary or a pdf file.

I look at this http://kb.mozillazine.org/Send_plain_text_attachments_as_real_attachments but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if attached .pdf files are automatically opened with e.g. Acrobat when clicking on an attachment (by opening your Thunderbird's preferences).

For me, the problem occurred as soon as I determined to not to be asked anymore what application I want the .pdf to be opened with. All outgoing mails immediately stopped having proper .pdf's attached.

I reset it to "ask me" and .pdf's are .pdf's again...

Comment: Pdf document are seted to "ask me". But I have 2 lines for pdf document. One with `application/pdf:.pdf` and another with `image/%22pdf?...`. Should I delete the second ?

Comment: The second one (`image/%22pdf?...`) seems to be an **invalid** MIME type. You could delete this without affecting functionality of downloads/attachments with **valid** MIME types. Nevertheless, resetting `application/pdf:.pdf` should bring back proper .pdf attachments, doesn't it?

Comment: @user127066  Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged.  Thanks.